# ElasticHttpError: 406, Elastic Search Error While indexing Data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, jvm

I am trying to index data in elastic search.

following is the version and other details about elastic search

```
{ "name" : "Tmqcj9W",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "HvwGfRrpR4-iaViCTm9ZwA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd92e7f",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-17T20:23:25.338Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0",
   }"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"}
```

The client side code to index data is in python:

```
es = ElasticSearch('http://localhost:9200/')
es.create_index(index_name)
es.bulk_index("index_name", "doc_type", [{"title":"this is title","desc":"this is description"}])
```

I am getting the following error.

*"pyelasticsearch.exceptions.ElasticHttpError: (406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')"*

After few searches I got few suggestions saying I need to set the content type to *"application/json"*, but I am not sure how to set this.
Can anyone help me with this ?.

Comment: your error says: 'Content-Type header [] is not supported' . Have you try to index without [ ] ? maybe in this way body={"title":"this is title","desc":"this is description"}

Comment: Which python API and version do you use ? You use `ElasticSearch` with capital 'S' so I assume it is not the low level python lib : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py

Comment: @Lupanoide I have tried both.

Comment: @MCMZL It is the newer version, with capital S.

Comment: Still need help with it?

Comment: I had some problem with the java installations in my pc. Moved to a cluster where same code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Issue was with elasticsearch python library. I downgraded the version to 6.
sudo pip3 install elasticsearch==6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `requests` directly, rather that the "thin wrapper" `elasticsearch` module.

In that context, when using bulk POST, you have to include the following header:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-ndjson'}
```

Example:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-ndjson'}        
index_url = f'{ES_URL}{INDEX_NAME}'
bulk_post_response, exception = requests.post(f'{index_url}/_bulk', data=self.bulk_post_object_str, headers=headers)
```

Equally importantly, the bulk post object string has to be a string formatted in a very specific way (not a json string as such). The details are given in the [Elasticsearch definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/bulk.html#bulk). In particular, see the link on that page, [Why the funny format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/distrib-multi-doc.html#bulk-format).