# Set Content-Type Header in elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to upload data to Elasticsearch through my python code. But I'm getting the following error:

`TransportError(406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')`

Details about the elasticsearch (server and client) installed on my system -

elasticsearch (server): 7.2.0
elasticsearch-py (client): 7.0.2

I've already looked at other solutions mentioned here ([ElasticHttpError: 406, Elastic Search Error While indexing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139986/elastichttperror-406-elastic-search-error-while-indexing-data)) and here (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/718).

I've upgraded the library installed in my system. But the error is still there.

The code I've been using:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

try:
    es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200/'],verify_certs=True)
except Exception as err:
    if not es.ping():
        raise ValueError("Connection failed")

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['result'])

res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1)
print(res['_source'])

es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")

res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
print("Got %d Hits:" % res['hits']['total']['value'])
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    print("%(timestamp)s %(author)s: %(text)s" % hit["_source"])
```

Based on elasticsearch-py documentation, it should automatically add `Content-Type` header but it doesn't seems to be working.

Please let me know how to manually add the headers through the python code.

Comment: Hmm, that's an odd problem. I am not actually sure that Content-Type is the problem. Can you include the full stack trace of the error you're getting in your code? There may be a way to get some more diagnostic info, like get the headers and body of the entire request, then we could diagnose it accurately.

Comment: @EmanuilTolev I'm running this code on Jupyter Notebook. Any idea on how to run stack track in it?

Comment: @MayanLai did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JamesTSnell I couldn't. I had to drop it mid-way and opt for a different solution.

Comment: Having the same issue. I tried the content type in REST client and get the same error. The query works when I change the content type to application/json in the request. It could be due to the ES configuration. I get: "Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json] is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on an old system. I installed new ES client, but default python on that system was python2 so it loaded some old python2 client.

You can print ES client version and location like this:

```
import elasticsearch
print(elasticsearch.__versionstr__)
print(elasticsearch.__path__)
```